# Does Visual Studio Code have an equivalent to CLion's CMake Profiles?

Tags: visual-studio-code, cmake, profile, clion

I'm following along [this tutorial](https://www.udemy.com/course/effective-modern-cmake-level-beginner/) to learn CMake.

In the tutorial, the instructor demonstrates encapsulating the setting of a CMake variable (i.e. a `-D` command line argument) in the `Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > CMake > Profiles` section of the CLion IDE.
(I believe it is the same as is documented here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/cmake-profile.html)

If I understand correctly, a "profile", in this context, is a container to group various CMake-related settings, such as toolchain and CMake options, in an enumerated manner. (By enumerate, I mean, I can have one "profile" named `FOO` that sets toolchain as `msvc.exe` and CMake options as `-DMYVAR="foo"`, and another profile named `BAR` that sets toolchain as `msvc.exe` and CMake options as `-DMYVAR="bar"`, etc.)

My question is: **does Visual Studio Code have this same concept of a CMake "profile"?**
I'd like to understand whether this concept of a "CMake profile" is an aspect of CMake itself, or an aspect of the IDE/development environment.